# SageMath import and test issues

Tags: python, sage

I installed Sage on my Ubuntu VM (using `apt-get install sage-upstream-binary`), but I've been having a lot of issues with ImportErrors in `sage -python`. (Some of them seem to have been caused by not calling `import sage.all` before other imports, but that didn't fix them all.)

In any case, I tried to look into it by running `sage -testall`, but this fails with the message `ValueError: unknown file extension ''`. I tried removing Sage and reinstalling, and updating all dependencies, but it won't run any of the tests, or do almost anything

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: What sort of imports are failing?  What directory are you in when you do `sage -testall`?  It might depend a lot on this.

Comment: `sage --testall` exits with the above message before attempting any tests or printing anything else at all.